# Stop Sticky Div at Certain Point for Jquery.Sticky.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery.sticky.js on my webpage. Div is properly working i.e sticky but I need to stop the div before my footer.

I had used below code for sticky DIV

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0});
   });`

My footer DIV has ID - #stop-sticky, how would I stop stickyness in the footer section?

Comment: it will be really helpful if you can add the markup  or provide a fiddle link

Comment: actually I don't use fiddle, I m new to Jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set bottomSpacing on the sticker. Your bottomSpacing value will be the footer's height + all the elements following it. I have attached a sample fiddle. Hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var stickyBottomOffset = $('footer').height();
    $("#sticker").sticky({topSpacing:0, bottomSpacing: stickyBottomOffset + $('nav').height() });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xLb6sgc2/